# compile and run Android apps from the console

Tags: compiling, command-line

I installed eclipse and all the sdk/jre etc... I can make Android Apps now and it's working, but often my eclipse crash.

I would like to know if it's possible to:

- compile
- build
- run

from the command line?

I use VIM to edit the files

Comment: Eclipse can definitely be a pain. This isn't stable yet, but I've heard good things about [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html). It's built on IntelliJ which most people prefer to Eclipse.

Comment: I tried android studio but it was very slow and crashed too.

Comment: It is possible, they tell you how in the android getting started tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html Just jump down to 'Create a Project with Command Line Tools'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem until I found a memory error. If you can't upgrade your memory here's what you can do:

1. Install dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf libsdl-dev libesd0-dev libwxgtk2.6-dev build-essential zip curl libncurses5-dev zlib1g-dev openjdk-6-jdk ant gcc-multilib g++-multilib
   sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ## if applicable
   sudo apt-get install ant1.7 ant-optional
   ```
2. Export paths:

   Open **.bashrc** file using an editor. If you use VI then `vi ~/.bashrc` and add the following 2 lines in your .bashrc file.

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/
   export JAVA_HOME
   ```

   Also, you can add these to compile from anywhere:

   open: **.profile**

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:~/development/android-sdk-linux/tools
   export PATH=$PATH:~/development/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools

   if [ -d "$JAVA_HOME/bin" ] ; then
     PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
   fi
   ```
3. Configure the android simulator:

   ```
   android avd
   ```

   And you can setup your simulator there
4. Build:

   ```
   ant debug
   ```

   or

   ```
   ant clean debug
   ```

   You might need to run:

   ```
   android update project --target <your build target> --path <path to LunarLander example>
   ```

   if you get:

   ```
   Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
   Build failed
   ```
5. Install the app:

   ```
   adb install ./bin/app-debug.apk
   ```

Sources:

- [Updating A Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject)
- [Running On Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#RunningOnEmulator)
- http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Comment: omg it works, thank you very much ... super fast to build as well +1.